# Laravel auto serve without command

Tags: laravel

Here is my question.
I want to serve Laravel project automatically.

Laravel project path:
/htdocs/Laravel_project

Url:
localhost/Laravel_project/public

When I go to the url,the project will be served automatically.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: what to you mean with served? You need a webserver like apache or nginx, if you don't want to use `php artisan serve`

Comment: Have you created the `htdocs` directory yourself or has an application created it?

Comment: I hope the project will activate automatically without command. I already built a web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a server( Nginx or apache ) if not setup in your machine. Through server only you can able to serve your application. I hope following link will help you with apache + laravel https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I will try it.